# Web Intelligence Sum every 5th row

Tags: business-intelligence, webi

I need to Sum every 5th row I can easily do it in excel but don't know how to create it in BI.
I need to sum the Usage for the 6 mo Usage column. Below is the Excel formula as I found out it doesn't like offset. =SUM(OFFSET($L$2,5*INT((ROW()-2)/5),,5))

It should look like the image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jTIx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have found this to work if anyone thinks it would be useful in their projects.

RowG: =Previous(Self; ([Part Nr.])) + 1

sum: =(Sum([6 Month Usage] Where ([RowG] <= 5)) In ([Part Nr.]))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5j4T.jpg)